# variables declared inside for loop which is inside a function - global or local(function)?

Tags: variables, global-variables, local

suppose, if a for loop is inside a function, and I declare a variable inside for loop, will that variable be global variable or local variable confined to that function in which the for loop is present?

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, loops do not have their own scope, so the variable's scope will be the scope of wherever the for loop lives. With that in mind, if the for loop is within a function, it will have local scope. One exception would be using `let x = something` in Javascript. This would release the memory at the end of the loops iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your response, robcarney. if I place the below for loop --> for(var i=0; i<5;i++) inside a function and then console.log(i) outside the function, it still displays i=0. Doesn't that mean that the variable i is accessible outside the function making it a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

Your question depends on a lot of factors i.e. programming language and the way you are declaring or using a variable.

For example in js:-

```
var y = 5;
function foo() {
    var x = 2;
    z = 5;
}
```

`var x` here is a local variable i.e. it cannot be used anywhere other than in the `function foo`.

`var y` on the other hand can be used globally as it is declared in the global scope

`var z` is not declared but it has been used to assign a value to it, so in javascript such a variable is `considered` to be declared in the global scope. So, it can be used outside the `function foo`